# Placing transcendental equation into simpler form

Tags: trigonometry, fluid-dynamics

I have come across a simple transcendental equation related to Stokes flow in a corner.

I am trying to place the transcendental equation $$n\tan n\alpha = (n-2)\tan(n-2)\alpha$$
into the form [with $x = 2(n-1)\alpha$]
$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = -\frac{\sin 2\alpha}{2\alpha}.$$

I have tried double angle formulas but can't seem to reduce it to this form . Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Take out $n$ as common factor

Comment: thank you @labbhattacharjee. I do not quite understand your suggestion. Are you suggesting expanding $\tan(n-2)\alpha$ using angle sum identities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation can be written as 
$$ n = \frac{2 \tan((n-2)\alpha)}{\tan((n-2)\alpha) - \tan(n\alpha)} $$
The second, with $x = 2(n-1)\alpha$, is
$$ n = \frac{\sin(2\alpha) - \sin(2(n-1)\alpha)}{\sin(2\alpha)} $$
So your task is to show the two right sides are equal.  Expand everything
in terms of $\sin(\alpha)$, $\cos(\alpha)$, $\sin(n\alpha)$ and $\cos(n\alpha)$ and use $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$ and it should work.

Comment: Robert, thank you! this worked well.